# MongoDB: order by two fields sum

Tags: mongodb

```
SELECT (a+b) as c FROM my_table ORDER BY c ASC;
```

How can I order by two columns sum in Mongo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do it easy without an extra action.

To sort on any computed value you need to store it in a document first or in other worlds you need to create extra field 'c', and store a + b in it with each update/insert  and only then sort on 'c' as usual.

Comment: It is very brutal solution. :(

Comment: From amount of work side mb it looks brutal, but from performance side it always faster then any calculations.

Comment: It looks brutal from sql side :)

Comment: it's data duplication : if query speed matters more to you than disk space, you should for this solution, otherwise, pick the mapreduce solution

Comment: @kamaradclimber: disk space is cheap, map reduce is slow process and not recommended to use synchronously. BTW, data dublication/denormalization is good known approach in nosql world... And if it possible to dublicate something you should try to dublicate first and only if it not possible - use m/r (async). Mongodb site and any mongodb book will say to you same..

Comment: @andrew : you're right, my comment was not clear but I do agree with you :)

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve like this query:

```
db.mycol.aggregate(
    [{$match:{tag:"xxx"}},
    {$project:{tag:1, count_a:1, count_b:1, factor:{$add: ["$count_a", "$count_b"]}}}, 
    {$sort:{factor:-1}}]
)
```